# How to store torrent links in a database?

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I have a python list in a spider containing magnet torrent list. Now how do i store this list/magnet torrent in a database fields ?
This is the code :

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):

    name = "myspider"
    allowed_domains = ["thepiratebay.se"]
    base_url = "http://www.thepiratebay.se/search/%s/"
    start_urls = []

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        movies = Movie.objects.all()
        for movie in movies:
            self.start_urls.append(self.base_url % movie.name)
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def parse(self, response):
        self.log('Hi, this is an item page! %s' % response.url)
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        items = hxs.select('//table/tr/td[contains(@class, "detName")]')
        item = items
        item_name = hxs.select('//a[@class="detLink"]/text()').extract()[1]
        print item_name  #list containing movie names      
        torrent_link = hxs.select('//a[@title="Download this torrent using magnet"]/@href').extract()[1]
        print torrent_link # torrent_link contains list of torrent links
```

Now i want to save these links in a database ??? How to do that ???

Comment: What did you try that doesn't work?

Comment: To help we would need lots more info. What database engine? What is the table structure? What python library? but mainly we would need to see what you have already tried?

Comment: I obtained a magnetic torrent list in spider and also created a models in which links will be saved but i've got no idea how to save torrent links in database fields..

Comment: don't write comments edit your question so we can see what have you done and what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have no experience of database programming with python I'd suggest you google for "python database tutorial" (I'd suggest starting with sqlite) and try following that and adapting it to your current script.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how to save to a DB then I *highly* recommend you do the [django tutorial here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/). It'll show you all the CRUD stuff with sqlite.